# Global search is not working in DataTable when server side is enabed in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to get form data from MongoDB server and showing it into data table using nodeJs.I successfully have done server-side pagination using npm Paginate v-2 plugin. But now the searching is not working. Below is my NodeJs and javascript files code. Please help me for searching.

NodeJs code

```
app.get('/gettable',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.query);
    user.paginate({},{
        page:Math.ceil(req.query.start / req.query.length) + 1,
        limit:parseInt(req.query.length)

    },function(err,result){
        var mytable = {
            draw:req.query.draw,
            recordsTotal:0,
            recordsFiltered:0,
            data:[],

        }
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json(mytable);
        } else {
            if(result.totalDocs > 0) {
                mytable.recordsTotal = result.totalDocs;
                mytable.recordsFiltered = result.totalDocs;

                for(var key in result.docs) {
                    mytable.data.push([
                        result.docs[key]['name'],
                        result.docs[key]['lastname'],
                        result.docs[key]['email'],
                        result.docs[key]['pass'],
                        result.docs[key]['birthdate'],
                        result.docs[key]['zipcode'],
                        result.docs[key]['phonenumber'],
                    ]);
                }
            }
            res.json(mytable);
        }

 });
```

DisplayTable.Js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#example').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": "http://localhost:8080/gettable"
   });
})
```

As I said, I am successfully getting data from a server and showing into data table with server-side pagination but searching is not working but in searching div whatever I search, I am getting that value in search array, like this

```
search: { value: 'svs', regex: 'false' },
  _: '1548653540009' }
```

But its not implementing in datatable to filter columns.

Comment: What you mean is you are doing a search of your database via a query (`req.query`) and it is not working (i.e. you are not getting back searched results) OR your db responds with the correct data and loads it into the HTML but you cannot search this data? Which one is it?

Comment: @EmmanuelNK I am getting data from a server and placing it into data table but Datatables default search bar is not working.I am using default data table using Bootstrap 4

Comment: @Arjun, global search will not work out of the box by just enabling server side. You have to add that code in your node js for search and then send the response back to datatable

Comment: okay @PrashantPokhriyal I got it.Can you please help me for how to do that in nodeJS.

Comment: @Arjun, I'm really sorry, I'm not a nodejs guy. Anyways I'll try to provide you a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54396060/custom-search-in-data-table-using-nodejs#comment95603762_54396060) that search will not work out of the box when server side is enabled in DataTable, it is because now the whole functionality, whether sorting, paging, limit, and search has to be implemented in the server. DataTable will only send the parameter needed for doing the functionality. Following is the code just for your reference, it is not tested and you may get an error also. You may get inputs from the following code. Feel free to edit the following code if in case of getting errors so that it can help future readers.

```
app.get('/gettable',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.query);

    var query = {},

       // array of columns that you want to show in table
       columns = ['name', 'lastname', 'email', 'pass', 'birthdate', 'zipcode', 'phonenumber',];

    // check if global search is enabled and it's value is defined
    if (typeof req.query.search !== 'undefined' && req.query.search.value != '') {

        // get global search value
        var text = req.query.search.value;

        // iterate over each field definition to check whether search is enabled
        // for that particular column or not. You can set search enable/disable
        // in datatable initialization.
        for (var i=0; i<req.query.columns.length; i++) {
            requestColumn = req.query.columns[i];
            column = columns[requestColumn.data];

            // if search is enabled for that particular field then create query
            if (requestColumn.searchable == 'true') {
                query[column] = {
                    $regex: text,
                };
            }
        }
    }

    user.paginate(query,{
        page:Math.ceil(req.query.start / req.query.length) + 1,
        limit:parseInt(req.query.length)

    },function(err,result){
        var mytable = {
            draw:req.query.draw,
            recordsTotal:0,
            recordsFiltered:0,
            data:[],

        }
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json(mytable);
        } else {
            if(result.totalDocs > 0) {
                mytable.recordsTotal = result.totalDocs;
                mytable.recordsFiltered = result.totalDocs;

                for(var key in result.docs) {
                    var data = [];
                    for(var column in columns) {
                        data.push(result.docs[key][column]);
                    }
                    mytable.data.push(data);
                }
            }
            res.json(mytable);
        }

 });
```

Comment: Thank you for help Prashant, this logic is not working var text is not getting anything,I think there is the problem.

Comment: I wrote your code inside the user. Paginate after the for loop, now I am getting value in console which I write in search bar so that means our var text is perfect but further logic might be incorrect.

Comment: Its not working yet Prashant ,In console the column is  giving only number ,like I have 7 columns so in console its printing 0 then in new line 1 ,then 2 till 7 but its not printing any data

Comment: okay when I write console.log(query[column]),its printing column value is0
{ '$regex': 'dvd' } ,column value is1
{ '$regex': 'dvd' }...till column 7 .so it means we are getting value in regex but nothing is changing in table.

Comment: I've updated my answer @Arjun, you can now make use of columns array to generate data in your for loop

Comment: @Arjun, you are getting column index becuase you are using ajax data source as array and not object. Actually dataTable support these two kinds of ajax response. You may check [this link](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) for more info. If you'll use data source as object , then you can get ride of that for loop easliy, which is creating `mytable.data`. Then in that case you can easily set `mytable.data = result.docs`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187412/discussion-between-arjun-and-prashant-pokhriyal).